# Localizable.strings broken since MonoTouch 5?

Tags: ios, localization, xamarin.ios, monodevelop, nsbundle

I opened up one of my old MonoTouch projects (coded in MT 4) after having upgraded to MT 5 and the localization doesn't work anymore. Nothing was changed since and it worked perfectly before the update. No matter what I do, it will only load the strings from `en.lproj`.

What I know so far :

- It's not because the Localization.strings are not set to the "Content" Build Action, I looked in
  **~/Library/Application Support/iPhone Simulator/5.0/Applications/GUID/MyApp.app/** by using "Show Package Content" and they are there. **(see image)**
- The localized images work (`Bundle.PathForResource("Images/MyImage", "png")`), only the strings seem broken (`Bundle.LocalizedString("MyString", "Comment", "")`)
- Changing `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture` or `Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture` doesn't do anything.
- Specifying the `lang.lproj` bundle before calling LocalizedString instead of using `NSBundle.MainBundle` doesn't do anything.

[image: .app content after building]

Comment: I cannot confirm this. My app supports EN and DE and if I switch the language in the Simulator's settings, the language will adjust correctly. I'm using NSBundle.MainBundle.LocalizedString(constant, "", "") to get my strings.

Comment: This looks like a bug. Can you file it here: http://bugzilla.xamarin.com with a complete test case?

Comment: It works correctly for me too.